# Is this infinite-dimensional normed linear space a complete one?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V=\{(x_1, x_2, ...)|x_i\in\mathbb{R}, i=1, 2, ...\}$ be a space of infinite-dimensional vectors. For each $x\in V$, define the norm $\lVert x\rVert =\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lvert x_i\rvert$. If the series doesn't converge, let $\lVert x\rVert=\infty$. The question is, does every Cauchy series $\{a_k\}$ converge in a point $a\in V$ ? It is a little different from the Banach space $\mathcal{l}_1$, however.

Comment: Norms are usually defined as $[0, \infty)$ valued functions. Are you saying that you want to include "infinite normed" sequences in your space too?

Comment: @jooi Yes, you're right... probably I should learn more about L1 space

Comment: @jooi what if I include "infinite normed" sequence as you said, and turn it into a mathematical analysis problem?

Comment: This post might be interesting: [Can a norm take infinite value? For example, $\|\cdot \|_1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289823/can-a-norm-take-infinite-value-for-example-cdot-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *extended norm* makes your vector space into a topological group, that is, addition is continuous. But multiplication $\mathbb R \times V$, $(\lambda,(x_n)_n)\mapsto (\lambda x_n)_n$ fails to be continuous.
Nevertheless, the uniformity given by $\|\cdot\|$ is complete: If $x^N$ is a Cauchy-sequence in $V$ then, for some $N_0$, the sequence $(x^N-x^{N_0})_{N\ge N_0}$ is in $\ell^1$ and Cauchy there. If $x\in \ell^1$ is the limit then you conclude $x^n\to x+X^{N_0}$ in $(V,\|\cdot\|)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your $V$ is the well known Banach space $l_1$ over the real numbers. Yes, it is a complete normed space.

Edited:
My first answer was wrong, and I accept the down-vote. The space $V$ is indeed not the Banach space $l_1$, as it proposes to included vectors of "infinite norm", but then $V$ is not a normed space because a norm must assign a positive number to any non-zero vector, and $\infty$ is unfortuntately not a positive number. So the question is meaningless -- There is no "norm" to check whether it is complete or not.

Comment: It is not; this definition of $V$ includes those $x$ with $\|x\|=\infty$.