# The space of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces

Is the space of continuous function from the set of the number $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (usually denoted by $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach space?
With the norm $\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left| {f\left( x \right)} \right|$.

Comment: What is the norm you are considering?

Comment: The norm $\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left| {f\left( x \right)} \right|$

Comment: This number need not be finite. For example, consider the identity function on $\mathbf{R}$. So your definition is not even a norm in the usual sense. :)

Comment: I think you mean **bounded** continuous functions (otherwise the norm is not well-defined).

Comment: If the function is not bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ we will take $\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in R} \left| {f\left( x \right)} \right|: = \infty $ for well defined problem

Comment: In general, $C(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach space w.r.t. your norm, if $\Omega$ is a compact topological space.

Comment: But $\mathbb{R}$ is complete but NOT COMPACT. So I think this problem is different

Comment: @TomekKania For $f(x)=x$, $\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in R} \left| {f\left( x \right)} \right|: = \infty $

Comment: As stated the answer is no, that is not a norm.  One may well ask if the space of real continuous functions has some other norm, but you run into similar problems with the unbounded continuous functions in $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: How about the norm is defined by $\left\| f \right\| = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in R} \left| {f\left( x \right)} \right|,\mbox{ if } f \mbox{ is bounded}}\\
{\infty ,\mbox{ if } f \mbox{ is not bounded}}
\end{array}} \right.$

Comment: A norm has to take its value in $\Bbb R_+$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289823/can-a-norm-take-infinite-value-for-example-cdot-1

Comment: Oh, my big mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course the original version of the question, "is $C(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$ a Banach space?" makes no sense unless we specify a norm. And of course the supremum is not a norm.

There *is* a related question that may be interesting: "Does there exist a norm on $C(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)$ making it into a Banach space?" Except that's not the right version of that question - the answer to *that* question is yes on Axiom of Choice grounds, but the norm we get has nothing to do with the fact that we're talking about continuous functions on $\Bbb R$.

The correct version of the possibly interesting question is this: "Does there exist a norm on $C(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)$ making it into a Banach space, and such that $||f_n||\to0$ if and only if $f_n\to 0$ uniformly on compact sets?"

The answer is no. This must be clear from some theorem in functional
analysis of which I'm unaware, saying that a topological 
vector space can be normed if and only if something. It's easy to show directly:

For $A>0$ say $X_A$ is the space of continuous functions that vanish off $[-A,A]$. Now, uniform convergence on compact sets, restricted to $X_A$, is the same as uniform convergence. So if $||.||$ were a norm as above then the restriction of $||.||$ to $X_A$ would be equivalent to the supremum norm; in particular $$||f||\ge c_A\sup|f(t)|\quad(f\in X_A).$$But now it's easy to construct a function $f$ so that $||f||=\infty$. (For example take $f=\sum f_n$ where $f_n$ is supported in $[2n,2n+1]$, and note that the partial sums converge to $f$ uniformly on compact sets, hence in "norm". But it's easy to give $f_n$ so that the "norms" of the partial sums are unbounded.)